# Plugging another relational DB to OpenDS

Tags: berkeley-db, opends

Currently I'm working on a project with opends. I have to upload more than 200k entries in the OpenDS. But unfortunately its fails at random times when file limit exceeding more than 10k - 15k.

When I google for that particular error (alert ID 9896233:  JE Database Environment corresponding to backend id userRoot is corrupt. Restart the Directory Server to reopen the Environment) it seems like openDS backend DB [BerklyDB] is not that reliable when adding massive number of entries. How can i plug in new commercial or open source reliable relational DB [Oracle/ H2] to the openDS. any configuration ? or do i have to change the openDS code ?

Answer (score 0):

First you should be aware that Oracle has pulled the plug on the OpenDS project and it is now completely stalled. Development continues as open source as the OpenDJ project : http://opendj.forgerock.org.

This said, I believe that there is a problem with your environment. When I was still working on OpenDS, our basic stress test was importing and running very high load against 10 Millions users. 200K entries is not massive number. My daily OpenDJ tests on my laptop are done with 100K to 1M entries. We have customers running in production with OpenDJ with more than 20M entries, growing 40% every 6 months !

Berkeley DB has been proved to be very scalable and reliable.
Things you might want to check : what is the maximum number of files that can be opened by a single process on your machine ? Linux defaults to 1024 and the limit may be easy to hit with OpenDS or OpenDJ. Are you using a local filesystem ? Berkeley DB is not supported on networked FS such as NFS or other NAS.

Finally, check the logs/errors file and your systems log. Chances are that one of them will have a message containing the root cause of the problem (most likely logs/errors).

Kind regards,

Ludovic Poitou

ForgeRock - Product Manager for OpenDJ

Comment: thank you very much, for your invaluable quick response. I will try out with OpenDJ during the day today and let u know the status.

Comment: Thanks again. Following exceptions were found in 'server.out' log. 

<DaemonThread name="Cleaner-2"/> caught exception: com.sleepycat.je.log.DbChecksumException: (JE 3.3.82) Location 0xb37/0x18529a expected 230608380 got 3064670493
com.sleepycat.je.log.DbChecksumException: (JE 3.3.82) Location 0xb37/0x18529a expected 230608380 got 3064670493
 at com.sleepycat.je.log.ChecksumValidator.validate(ChecksumValidator.java:96)
 ..

Exit

Comment: <DaemonThread name="Checkpointer"/> caught exception: Environment invalid because of previous exception: com.sleepycat.je.log.DbChecksumException: (JE 3.3.82) Location 0xb37/0x18529a expected 230608380 got 3064670493
Environment invalid because of previous exception: com.sleepycat.je.log.DbChecksumException: (JE 3.3.82) Location 0xb37/0x18529a expected 230608380 got 3064670493
 at com.sleepycat.je.log.ChecksumValidator.validate(ChecksumValidator.java:96)
 ...
Exiting